# Multiple POST requests in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I need to have multiple POST requests on a single page of my WebApp made in Python + JS

Here is my App.py code:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #user inputs
        value1 = request.form.get('first')
        value2 = request.form.get('second')
        value3 = request.form.get('third')

        #api call 
        url = 'http://myapiurl.com/myapi/'
        payload = {
                    "perfid" : value1,
                    "section" : {
                        "hostname" : value2,
                        "iteration" : value3,
                        "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"
                        }
                }


        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
        returnData = {}

        if r.status_code == 200:
            returnData["status"] = "SUCCESS"
            returnData["result"] = json.loads(r.text)
            return jsonify(returnData)
        else:
            returnData["status"] = "ERROR"
            return jsonify(returnData)

        #print(r.status_code, r.headers['content-type'])
        #print(r.text)
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now I need to have multiple such POST request API calls on the same page.
By multiple POST requests I mean that I need to consume one more API within the same page.

eg: I am having another API at http://myapiurl.com/myapi2/ and I need to consume that too with the same POST request as just one parameters is different and the result will be different.

```
url = 'http://myapiurl.com/myapi2/'
        payload = {
                    "perfid" : value1,
                    "section" : {
                        "hostname" : value2,
                        "iteration" : value3,
                        "sectionname" : "DIFFERENT VALUE"
                        }
                }


        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
        returnData = {}
```

Here is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");


  $('form').on('submit', function() { 

    console.log("the form has beeen submitted");

    // grab values
    valueOne = $('input[name="perfid"]').val();
    valueTwo = $('input[name="hostname"]').val();
    valueThree = $('input[name="iteration"]').val();


    console.log(valueOne)
    console.log(valueTwo)
    console.log(valueThree)



    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/",
      dataType:'json',
      data : { 'first': valueOne,'second': valueTwo,'third': valueThree},
      success: function(data) {


        var x = parseInt(data.result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.AVG);




       if(x>80)
            {
                var res = data.result.sectoutput.summarystats.Avg.AVG;
                var p = '<p>CPU may be overloading.</p>';
                $('#result').append(p);

            }
        else
            {
                var p = '<p>Normal Usage going on.</p>';
                $('#result').append(p);
            }


      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Can anyone help me in doing this ?
Is this even possible?

Or can anyone point me where I can understand how to process multiple POST requests? 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure what you are trying to do here. Can you try explaining it differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have two calls from jQuery if the client have to do the two calls. It is called deferred.then(). Have a look at this links https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Basically instead of one ajax call you will have two, the first will wait the second to be done and then you can expose your combined data in the html. You will call the first API. When you have success you will call the second API and finally you will combine the data from both requests and show it on the screen. The syntax's is something like:

```
var request = $.ajax( "http://myapiurl.com/myapi/", { dataType: "json" } ),

chained = request.then(function( data ) {
   return $.ajax( "http://myapiurl.com/myapi2/", { data: { user: data.userId }  }    );
});

chained.done(function( data ) {
   // data retrieved from url2 as provided by the first request
});
```

Another cleaner option is to use the jQuery "post" deferred function instead of ajax like so:

```
$.post( "http://myapiurl.com/myapi/", 
  function( response1 ) {
      $.post( "http://myapiurl.com/myapi2/", 
         function( response2 ) {
           //combine your data here and display it
           var result = []
           result.append(response1)
           result.append(response2)
           $(".result").html(result);
         }
       );
  }
);
```

If you need the first API to call the second API before it passes the data to the client, then another option is to call the second API within the first API with requests. Something like:

```
@app.route("/")
def your_method_name():
    #get the data from the current first API
    data = {
                "perfid" : value1,
                "section" : {
                    "hostname" : value2,
                    "iteration" : value3,
                    "sectionname" : "FIRST VALUE"
                    }
            } 
    #then call the second api 
    r = requests.post('http://myapiurl.com/myapi2/')
    data2 = json.loads(r.text) #this should give you the second payload with the different value if the call to the second API is successful

   #combine data and data2 in a lsit
   list = []
   list.append(data)
   list.append(dat2)

   #return the combined data
   return jsonify(list)
```